# Ошибка : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404

Tags: javascript, php

есть функция JS,которая передаёт GET - запросом данные

```
function xttp(){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "url?data=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify('London'));
        xhr.open("GET", url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                //console.log(json.email + ", " + json.password);
            }
        };
        xhr.send(); //ошибка на эту строку 
    }
```

и есть php - файл,где этот запрос принимается :

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");
$v = json_decode(stripslashes($_GET["data"]));
echo json_encode($v);
?>
```

Comment: и 404 о чем вам говорит?

Comment: не найден файл ?

Comment: следовательно, если кода, генерирующего 404, в указанном файле нет, то дело до него собственно не доходит, и проблема не в пхп файле, а надо изучать что происходит до этого? 1) некорректный URL 2) реврайты сервера